# Assembly Jump Instruction Address Calculation

Tags: c, assembly, x86, gdb

I see the following instruction in gdb

```
jmp    *0x804a09c(,%eax,4)
```

Just prior to exececution I types these commands:

```
(gdb)p/x *0x804a09c
$40 = 0x8048e0e

(gdb) p $eax
$41 = 6
```

So when I try to calculate the address I will jump to, I get:

```
(gdb) p/x *0x804a09c + 4*$eax
0x8048e26
```

However, the jump actually goes to address 0x8048ead. What's wrong with my calculation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jmp    *0x804a09c(,%eax,4)
```

means to jump to the address that is stored at the result of this calculation`0x804a09c(,%eax,4)`, the `*` on the whole not on just `0x804a09c`. AT&T syntax can be misleading, Intel syntax is more clear here:

```
jmp    DWORD PTR [eax*4+0x804a09c]
```

so it should be:

```
(gdb) p/x *(0x804a09c + 4 * $eax)
```